# Does the Crusader skill Consecration stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

The legendary flail [Inviolable Faith](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/inviolable-faith) casts [Consecration](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/crusader/active/consecration) under all my allies too.

If my allies and I are standing close together, so that the Consecration casts overlaps:

1. Will each receive bonus healing or just the normal amount from 1 cast?
2. For the Frozen Ground rune, will enemies be slowed beyond 60%?
3. For the Frozen Ground rune, will enemies have multiple chances to be frozen?
4. For the Shattered Ground rune, will enemies take additional fire damage?

Comment: my first guess is no, DoT aoes rarely stack when they're from the same person.

Comment: @z' - Also my first impression. *However*, affects where you leave fire on the ground *do* stack, and if it didn't stack that may mean this ability was cheated out of some of the guaranteed benefit of multiple casts. I think the only way to actually get an answer to this would be to test it.

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikia pages for Diablo 3](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Consecration) state that the healing effects and damage of multiple Consecration do stack, however the secondary effects do not. This means that:

1. Yes, multiple healing bonuses.
2. No, enemies can only be frozen once per 4 seconds and the secondary effects do not stack.
3. While I don't know for sure, mechanically it's likely that each Consecration will have it's own chance of freezing the enemy, but once the enemy is frozen it will then become immune to all other freezing effects for 4 seconds.
4. Yes, damage stacks.